# How can I calculate the partial derivative to a function that uses matrices with frobenius norm?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative

I have not taken calculus for while so I need some help with the following partial derivative. If I am shown how to do this one I should be able to figure out the rest of them.

So I have

$$f(A,B,C) = ||P - AB^T||^2 + ||Q - AC^T||^2$$

where A,B,C,Q,P are matrices and $|| ||$ is the frobenius norm.

and I want partial derivative:
$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial B}$$

Comment: Differentiating with respect to a matrix is quite a bit more advanced than what is covered in typical calculus courses! You may have to look up the identities for [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities), and use the fact that $\|A\|^2 = {\rm tr}(A^TA)$.

Comment: @Rahul ok thanks. Yeah I have been asked to perform this derivative and it isn't like anything I have seen before. I only have undergraduate calculus courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
and define new variables
$$\eqalign{
 X &= BA^T-P^T \cr
 Y &= CA^T-Q^T \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of these new symbols. Then find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 f &= X:X + Y:Y \cr
df &=2X:dX + 2Y:dY \cr
 &= 2X:dB\,A^T + 0 \cr
 &= 2XA:dB \cr
 &= 2(BA^TA - P^TA):dB \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial B} &= 2(BA^TA - P^TA) \cr\cr
}$$
There are lots of rules for rearranging the terms in a Frobenius product, which follow from the properties of the underlying trace function.

For example, all of the following are equivalent 
$$\eqalign{
 A:BC &= B^TA:C\cr &= AC^T:B\cr &= A^T:(BC)^T\cr &= BC:A \cr
}$$